# Difficulty Loading a CSV File with Dask

Tags: python, out-of-memory, dask, dask-distributed

I'm facing difficulties loading a substantial CSV file using Dask. The file size is around 30 GB, and I'm using Dask because my machine's RAM is insufficient for pandas. Despite reading multiple blogs and posts claiming that Dask can handle larger CSV files on a home laptop, I haven't been successful. My machine has 126 GB of RAM, 32 cores, and a swap space of 10 GB. Surprisingly, a friend of mine managed to load the same CSV file using his MAC laptop with 64 GB of RAM. While I understand there may be missing details, such as specific error messages or additional information about my machine, I feel I'm making a mistake unrelated to those factors.

I've attempted the "simple way" and alternative way using the Dask client. In the "simple way" approach, I estimate the chunk size based on the available memory and number of cores.
The "simple way code":

```
def estimate_chunk_size() -> int:
    # Calculate available memory and number of cores
    memory_available_bytes = psutil.virtual_memory().available
    num_cores = os.cpu_count()

    # Calculate chunk size based on memory and cores
    chunk_size_bytes = int((memory_available_bytes / num_cores) / 6)

    return chunk_size_bytes

def csv_loader(csv_path: str) -> dd.DataFrame:
    try:
        # Get file size
        file_size_gb = os.path.getsize(csv_path) / (1024 ** 3)
        
        # Specify data types
        dtype = {
            'end_date': 'object',
            ...
            'user_last_update': 'object'
        }
        
        # Estimate chunk size
        blocksize = estimate_chunk_size()

        # Load CSV using Dask
        csv_data = dd.read_csv(csv_path, assume_missing=True, blocksize=blocksize, dtype=dtype)

        return csv_data

    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Handle file not found error
        ...

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle other exceptions
        ...
```

When using this approach, this is the console output:

```
Columns (19,20,21,22,23,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,110) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

^C
Process finished with exit code 137
```

In the second approach, I tried opening a Dask client with the maximum number of workers. Here's a modified version of the code:

```
from dask.distributed import Client

def csv_loader(csv_path: str) -> dd.DataFrame:
    try:
        # Get file size
        file_size_gb = os.path.getsize(csv_path) / (1024 ** 3)

        # Specify data types
        dtype = {
            'end_date': 'object',
            ...
            'user_last_update': 'object'
        }

        # Estimate chunk size
        blocksize = estimate_chunk_size()

        # Create Dask client with maximum number of workers
        with Client(n_workers=psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)) as client:
            # Load CSV using Dask
            csv_data = dd.read_csv(csv_path, assume_missing=True, blocksize=blocksize, dtype=dtype)

        return csv_data

    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Handle file not found error
        ...

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle other exceptions
        ...
```

Comment: Remember that a CSV file's size is practically unrelated to its size in memory.  The string "3.2" requires 3 bytes as a string, but 8 bytes as a double-precision float, and objects require much more space.  What do you intend to DO with this data?  Can't you handle it a chunk at a time?

Comment: I process the data (removing nulls, columns with a single value and etc) and then train catboost classifer.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved loading the file when I decreased the block size.

I changed this line: `chunk_size_bytes = int((memory_available_bytes / num_cores) / 6)`

to:`chunk_size_bytes = int((memory_available_bytes / num_cores) / 20)`

in the `estimate_chunk_size` method.

It took 35 min to upload the CSV file.